# Ширина родительского элемента

Tags: html, css

Есть такая конструкция:

```
<div id="parent">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
   <img src="">
</div>
```

И такой css код:

```
#parent
{
   height: 100%;
}
#parent img
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%
}
```

Возникла такая проблема: как задать #parent такую же ширину как и у #parent img?
width: 100%; увы не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном контексте никак, даже js не поможет. Если у img убрать `height: 100%` то можно с помощью js определить размеры img и задать размеры для родительского контейнера.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. У img position: absolute для crossfade, на знаете варианты crossfade, где не потребуется position: absolute?

Comment: Для реализации image crossfade не нужно знать размеры контейнера `#parent`, [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/5M2PD/4/)
Так же как вариант, можете воспользоваться простой библиотекой 
[cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/), [пример](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php).  Ни строчки js кода, подключаете библиотеку, указывается класс для контейнера и всё.

Comment: Мне размеры контейнера #parent нужны не для crossfade, по этому и задал вопрос

Comment: В таком случаи, попробуйте продублировать первое изображение и добавить ему свойство
`position: static; visibility: hidden;`, [пример](http://codepen.io/olegatro/pen/mJGvOe)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо